# Cannot acces window object in DotNetBrower

Tags: javascript, json, browser, window, dotnetbrowser

I have no idea what I am doing wrong, I had it working, did a few things and now can't get it working again...the object is there, butI cannot access it, always comes back as undefined.  I am passing a JSON string to javascript via the DotNetBrowser window.SetObject() Property...

[image: Here is the SerializedObject passed to the window Object Property "Teams"]

However, when I attempt to do JSON.parse(window.Teams) I get the following:

[image: its undefined??]

I'm unsure what to do from here...the object clearly is there, but its not accessible.  How can I access the object?

EDIT: Here is the code in .NET

```
Class MainWindow
    Public Shared NewGameScreen As New NewGame
    Public window As JSValue
    Public DBObj As New DBObject
    Public page As String = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory()

    Sub New()
        Try
            BrowserPreferences.SetChromiumSwitches("--remote-debugging-port=9222", "--disable-web-security", "--allow-file-access-from-files")

            InitializeComponent()
            '##########################################################################
            '##########################################################################
            '################## DOTNETBROWSER INITIALIZATION ##########################
            '##########################################################################
            '##########################################################################

            'Replace the absolute path with the relative path
            page = page.Replace("bin\x86\Debug\", "Web\index.html")

            browserView1.Preferences.JavaScriptEnabled = True
            browserView1.Preferences.ImagesEnabled = True
            browserView1.Preferences.AllowRunningInsecureContent = True

            'load the page
            browserView1.Browser.LoadURL(page)

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub

    Private Sub LoadDBObjects()
        'Create the window object to pass .NET values to JS Land
        window = browserView1.Browser.ExecuteJavaScriptAndReturnValue("window")
        window.AsObject().SetProperty("Teams", DBObj.Teams)
        'window.AsObject().SetProperty("Owners", DBObj.Owners)
        'window.AsObject().SetProperty("Personnel", DBObj.Personnel)
        'window.AsObject().SetProperty("Coaches", DBObj.Coaches)
        'window.AsObject().SetProperty("Players", DBObj.Players)
        'window.AsObject().SetProperty("Draft", DBObj.Draft)

    End Sub

    Private Async Sub browserView_FinishLoadingFrameEvent(sender As Object, e As Events.FinishLoadingEventArgs)
        If e.IsMainFrame Then
            'Wait for the browser to finish loading, then load the page
            Await Task.Run(Sub()
                               LoadDBObjects()
                           End Sub) 'Initialize the DBObjects to load
            'set up debugging at http://127.0.0.1:9222
            browserView2.Browser.LoadURL(browserView2.Browser.GetRemoteDebuggingURL())
        End If
    End Sub

End Class

''' <summary>
''' Class to create the DB Objects to be used in JavaScript
''' </summary>
Public Class DBObject
    Public SQLTable As New SQLiteDataFunctions 'Create the SQLite object
    ReadOnly MyDB As String = "Football" 'set the DB Name
    Public Property Teams As String
    Public Property Owners As String
    Public Property Personnel As String
    Public Property Coaches As String
    Public Property Players As String
    Public Property Draft As String

    Public Sub New()
        'Load up the database tables
        SQLTable.LoadTable(MyDB, TeamDT, "Teams")
        SQLTable.LoadTable(MyDB, OwnerDT, "Owners")
        SQLTable.LoadTable(MyDB, PersonnelDT, "Personnel")
        SQLTable.LoadTable(MyDB, CoachDT, "Coaches")
        SQLTable.LoadTable(MyDB, PlayerDT, "RosterPlayers")
        SQLTable.LoadTable(MyDB, DraftDT, "DraftPlayers")
        CreateDBObjects()
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Serialize the DataTables into JSON and expose them to JS
    ''' </summary>
    Public Sub CreateDBObjects()
        'Now we need to serialize the objects for use in Javascript
        Dim Settings As New JsonSerializerSettings() 'create settings that will ensure no duplicates
        Settings.ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace

        Teams = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(TeamDT, Settings)
        Owners = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(OwnerDT)
        Personnel = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(PersonnelDT)
        Coaches = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(CoachDT)
        Players = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(PlayerDT)
        Draft = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DraftDT)

        TeamDT = Nothing
        OwnerDT = Nothing
        PersonnelDT = Nothing
        CoachDT = Nothing
        PlayerDT = Nothing
        DraftDT = Nothing
    End Sub

End Class
```

And the JavaScript used to get it...

```
//<!--GLOBAL ANGULAR-->
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('routerApp', ['ui.router', 'formly', 'formlyBootstrap', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngMessages',
            'ui.grid', 'restangular', 'formly_templates', 'nya.bootstrap.select',
            'rzModule', 'ui.mask', 'angular-3d-carousel', 'ui.grid.autoResize'])

        .service('DB', function ($q) {
            this.load = {
                isLoading: false,
                data: []
            };

            this.setIsLoading = function (value) {
                this.load.isLoading = value;
            };

            this.setData = function (data) {
                this.load.data = data;
            };

            this.getNumEnding = function (number) {
                var defer = $q.defer();
                var num = number.toString();
                var result = '';
                switch (num[num.length - 1]) { //gets the last digit of the number
                    case '1': result = 'st'; break;
                    case '2': result = 'nd'; break;
                    case '3': result = 'rd'; break;
                    default: result = 'th';
                }
                defer.resolve(result);
                return result;
            };
        })

        .service('dataService', ['$timeout', '$q', function ($timeout, $q) {
            //var fs = window.fs;
            var sql = window.SQL;

            define(function (require) {
                //fs = require('fs');
                sql = require('sql');
            });

        this.getData = function () {
            var defer = $q.defer();
            $timeout(function () {

                var DB = [];
                DB.Teams = window.Teams;
                defer.resolve(DB);
            }, 0);
            return defer.promise;
        };
    }])

    .run(function (DB, dataService) {
        DB.setIsLoading(true),
            dataService.getData(),
            //DB.setData(data);
            DB.setIsLoading(false);
    })

    .controller('loadCtrl', ["$scope", "DB", function loadCtrl($scope, DB) {
        $scope.appState = DB.load;
        $scope.Teams = DBTeams; // still not getting the Data....
        console.log(DBTeams);
    }])

    .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

        $stateProvider

            // HOME STATES AND NESTED VIEWS ========================================
            .state('home', {
                url: '/home',
                templateUrl: 'home.html',
                resolve: { //attempting to ensure data loads before it finishes getting the page, still not working
                    DBTeams: function () {
                        return window.Teams;
                    }
                }
            })
            //START GAME--MAIN
            .state('Start', {
                url: '/start',
                templateUrl: 'New_Game_Wizard/new_game.html',
                controller: 'newGameCtrl',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            })
            //nested Start states--url will be Start/profile
            .state('Start.career', {
                url: '/career',
                pararms: { model: null },
                templateUrl: 'New_Game_Wizard/Start/Start-career.html',
                controller: 'careerCtrl',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            })

            .state('Start.career2', {
                url: '/career2',
                params: { model: null },
                templateUrl: 'New_Game_Wizard/Start/Start-career2.html',
                controller: 'career2Ctrl',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            })

            .state('Start.career3', {
                url: '/career3',
                params: { model: null },
                templateUrl: 'New_Game_Wizard/Start/Start-career3.html',
                controller: 'career3Ctrl',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            })

            //Team Selection screen
            .state('Start.teamSelect', {
                url: '/teamSelect',
                params: { model: null },
                templateUrl: 'New_Game_Wizard/Start/Start-teamSelect.html',
                controller: 'teamSelectCtrl',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            })

            .state('Start.single', {
                parent: 'Start',
                url: '/single',
                templateUrl: 'New_Game_Wizard/Start/Start-single.html'
            })

            .state('Start.quick', {
                parent: 'Start',
                url: '/quick',
                templateUrl: 'New_Game_Wizard/Start/Start-quick.html'
            })

            .state('Start.situation', {
                parent: 'Start',
                url: '/situation',
                templateUrl: 'New_Game_Wizard/Start/Start-situation.html'
            })

            .state('Load', {
                url: '/load',
                templateUrl: 'test.html',
                controller: 'testCtrl'
            })

            .state('Exit', {
                url: '/exit',
                templateUrl: 'exit_game.html'
            })

            .state('Main', {
                url: '/dashboard',
                templateUrl: 'Main/index.html',
                controller: 'mainCtrl',
                controllerAs: 'vm',
                lazyLoad: () => System.import('/Main/index.html')
            })

            // ABOUT PAGE AND MULTIPLE NAMED VIEWS =================================
            .state('settings', {
                // we'll get to this in a bit
            })

            .state('menu', {
            });
    }])

    .run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams',
      function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
          $rootScope.$state = $state;
          $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
      }]);
})();
```

Comment: Could you please attach your .NET code that demonstrates how the window object is obtained and modified? It is difficult to determine the exact cause of the issue without it.

Comment: I attached it above

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code that explains how to pass a JSON string from .NET to JavaScript in general case:

```
window = browser.ExecuteJavaScriptAndReturnValue("window")
window.AsObject().SetProperty("myObject", New JSONString("[123, 'Hello']"))
```

In this case, on the JavaScript side, this JSON string will be parsed and converted to appropriate JavaScript object or objects. After performing such call, you can access this object in your JavaScript code through the `window.myObject` property.

Here is a link to the corresponding documentation article:
http://dotnetbrowser-support.teamdev.com/documentation/working-with-json

Comment: OK I found the issue...the page is loading before the code finishes running to get the Object--when it checks for the object it is still undefined...when I check for the object on the next page, it is there. In this case it doesn't really matter, but how can I make sure the object loads before the page does for the future?

Comment: In a few cases JS context events can be used to execute JavaScript  before the page is loaded completely: http://dotnetbrowser-support.teamdev.com/documentation/javascript-context-events

Comment: The strange this was I had this working right out of the box just fine and now I can't figure out how to get back to that point...the object was always there previously...